# Why is the dictionary key being converted to an inherited class type?

Tags: python, class, dictionary

My code looks something like this:

```
class SomeClass(str):
    pass

some_dict = {'s':42}

>>> type(some_dict.keys()[0])
str
>>> s = SomeClass('s')
>>> some_dict[s] = 40
>>> some_dict # expected: Two different keys-value pairs
{'s': 40}
>>> type(some_dict.keys()[0])
str
```

Why did Python convert the object `s` to the string "s" while updating the dictionary `some_dict`?

Comment: The question to ask yourself is, 'why do these instances hash to the same value?'

Comment: What is the output of the last line, since that is literally what your question in the title is about?

Comment: ... because `s` is a string with a value of `"s"`?

Comment: @1313e updated the output.

Comment: I see, so both the object `s` and string "s" have the same hash and this hash is used to insert the values in the dictionary, right?

Comment: @Satwik - exactly :-)

Comment: but that's a nice question anyway.

Comment: Thanks @snakecharmerb! I didn't knew that hash values were ignorant of the object type.

Comment: @Satwik "hash values" aren't ignorant of anything. They are equal to whatever the object's `__hash__` method returns. By subclassing `str` and not implementing `__hash__` itself, `SomeClass` behaves exactly like `str` does, hence `hash('s')` and `hash(SomeClass('s'))` return the exact same value. `class A(str): pass ; print(hash('s') == hash(A('s'))) ; True`

Comment: Okay, now I get it. The `__hash__` method for `SomeClass` was inherited from `str` class and that's why the hashes are same.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Whilst the hash value is related, it is not the main factor.
 It is equality that is more important here. That is, objects may have the same hash value and not be equal, but equal objects must have the same hash value (though this is not strictly enforced). Otherwise you will end up with some strange bugs when using `dict` and `set`.

Since you have not defined the `__eq__` method on `SomeClass` you inherit the one on `str`. Python's builtins are built to allow subclassing, so `__eq__` returns true, if the object would otherwise be equal were it not for them having different types. eg. `'s' == SomeClass('s')` is true. Thus it is right and proper that `'s'` and `SomeClass('s')` are equivalent as keys to a dictionary.

To get the behaviour you want you must redefine the `__eq__` dunder method to take into account type. However, when you define a custom equals, python stops giving you an automatic `__hash__` dunder method, and you must redefine it as well. But in this case we can just reuse `str.__hash__`.

```
class SomeClass(str):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (
            type(self) is SomeClass
            and type(other) is SomeClass
            and super().__eq__(other)
        )

    __hash__ = str.__hash__

d = {'s': 1}
d[SomeClass('s')] = 2

assert len(d) == 2
print(d)
```

prints: `{'s': 2, 's': 1}`

Comment: Thank you for this! Really big TIL, worth mention that if you try to print `d['s']` you will get only the "first" result(where "first" depends on your python version: 3.6 will give you the first inserted value, while 3.5 and lower the first in memory. Also a typo in the last line`print(d)`

Comment: excellent answer for a sunday :) and excellent for a weekday as well.

Comment: <nitpicking> If there was a reason to actually do this, it might be better to actually implement a *different* `__hash__` and avoid the performance loss coming from the collisions with `str.__hash__`, especially if there are multiple classes inherited from `str` and all used as keys.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really good question. Firstly, when put (key, value) pair into `dict`, it uses hash function to get the hash value of key and check if this hash code is present. If present, then `dict` compares the object with same hash code. If two objects are equal (`__eq__(self, other)` return `True`), then, it would update the value, which is why your code encounters such behavior.

Given `SomeClass` is not even modified, so `'s'` and `SomeClass('s')` should have the same hash code and `'s'.__eq__(SomeClass('s'))` will return True.